# How to scale nodes to tags using API calls

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3.js force directed graph with the nodes set to Stack Overflow user tags. I'm having a bit of trouble scaling the nodes so that they represent the tag's score, but I'm unsure of how to scale the scores because they are drastically different.

How would I go about scaling the following tags for instance?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "answer_score": 161398,
      "tag_name": "c#"
    },
    {
      "answer_score": 96912,
      "tag_name": "java"
    }
}]
```

So far I only have a test data set running with the graph

```
var featureContent={nodes:[{name:"osx",group:0,degree:5},.....(other nodes)
```

With links set up too

```
links:[{source:0,target:89,color:0},....(other links)
```

Then I have a JS method featureGraph called in the HTML

```
featureGraph(featureContent,1150,1070,0,"#graph",90,-100);
```

Here is how my layout is set up:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.gravity(.05)
.distance(distance)
.charge(charge)
.size([width, height]);
```

Comment: Add what you have tried so far :) As they are really different maybe set up some ranges, so if the answer_score falls in a certain range, change the radius accordingly

Comment: In the HTML I have a fuction that is called in the graph.js: featureGraph(featureContent,1150,1070,0,"#graph",90,-100);                      Then my force layout is set up like this:                                               var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .distance(distance)
    .charge(charge)
    .size([width, height]);

Comment: add it to your question mate, no use in comments without any formatting etc. Better yet use https://jsfiddle.net/ to create your visualization, save it, add the URL to the fiddle in the question and we can see your problem in action :)

Comment: Ive edited it there :)

Comment: So what does featureGraph() do ? You need an example to show us rather than bits and pieces of code. It's kinda hard to guess what things happen in your code without the code there